# Exclude Relation Data Based on Condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-relations

I am working on laravel many to many relations. I have two tables and a pivot table. The table structure is something like this:

Table studies:

```
-id
-name
-code
```

Table sites:

```
-id
-name
-type
```

Pivot Table study_sites:

```
-id
-study_id
-site_id
```

Models for Both Tables:

**Site Model:**

```
public function studies()
    {
        /** model, pivot_table, current table id in pivot table, relation table id in pivot table */
        return $this->belongsToMany(Study::class, 'study_sites', 'site_id', 'study_id')->withPivot("study_site_id");
    }
```

**Study Model:**

```
public function sites()
    {
        /** model, pivot_table, current table id in pivot table, relation table id in pivot table */
        return $this->belongsToMany(Site::class, 'study_sites', 'study_id', 'site_id')->withPivot('study_site_id');
    }
```

Now I want to get all those sites that are not assigned to a particular study (e.g study_id, "!=", 2).
In this regard, I have used:

```
    $sites = Site::query();
    $sites = $sites->whereDoesntHave('studies', function($query) {
                        $query->where('study_id', '!=', 2);
                       })->get();
   dd($sites);
```

I have applied other logic too but didn't find any solution. I will appreciate it if anyone guides me in this regard.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline relationship existence queries, like below:

```
$sites = Site::query()->whereRelation('studies', 'pivot.study_id', '!=', 2)->get();
```

Comment: so it will give me the sites that are not assigned to study_id 2, but assigned to all other studies and I don't want that.
I have study_id stored in session, so regardless of other studies I just want to filter it for study_id 2.
I hope my point is clear now?

Comment: Well you can change the operator in the query and put another value instead of '2',

Comment: Could I understand what you mean?

Comment: I guess NO, actually I am in a study right. I want to filter all remaining sites that are not assigned to this study which is for example "study_id, 2". I don't care to which other studies these sites are assigned.
The above query will look for something else brother because whereRelation will even ignore all the sites that are even assigned to other studies. 
e,g I have 6 sites, 2-sites are assigned to "Study_id, 1", similarly 2 sites are assigned to "study_id, 2" and in the last 2 sites are assigned to "study_id, 3".
So above query will return null because all of the sites have relation!

Comment: Lets me make it further simplify, Lets assume we have 6 sites. We assigned 2 sites to (study_id, 2).
Now I want to fetch the remaining 4 sites that are not assigned to this current study.
I hope it make sense now!